# select date that is less or equal to current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am trying to select the date in the field end_date that is less or equal to current date but did not work and my field end_date as the same date format(08-09-2014) data as current date below is my code thanks

```
$currentdate = date("d-m-Y");
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE end_date <= '$currentdate'";            
$result1 = mysql_query ($query1) or die('query error');
while( $line1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){   
echo $line1['end_date'];
}
```

Comment: What type `end_date` has?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    SELECT * FROM location WHERE end_date <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

try with -

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE end_date <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE `end_date` <= '$currentdate'";            
$result1 = mysql_query ($query1) or die('query error');
while( $line1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){   
echo $line1['end_date'];
}
```

try this... must have in database  date format;;

Answer (score 0):

If your currentdate is independent of the system date (e.g. if you are operating over different timezones), and if, for some reason, your end_date is not a date type, then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM location 
WHERE str_to_date(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y') <= str_to_date('$currentdate', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

where the format can be changed to match your inputs.

If you want to compare dates, then make sure you are comparing ***dates*** and not strings.